# sails.js Getting a POST payload with text/plain content type

Tags: node.js, post, express, sails.js

I'm developing a sails.js (node.js framework based on express) aplication, which is going great but ]I can't solve this detail...

I need to send POST requests cross domain from internet explorer 8 and 9. For that I'm forced to use xDomainRequest object, wich doesn't allow to set a Content type header.

So, when the request gets to the server the content type is "text/plain", which doesn't fire the bodyParser express middleware, so my req.body is an empty object and I can't see the payload I'm sending from the client.

For this I've tried two things with no luck:

First I wanted to set a header to the request in my first middleware, which is of course not available:

```
  req.set("Content-type", "Apli.....
```

Then, I created a middleware that listens to req.on('data'), like this:

```
        var data = "";
    req.on('data', function(chunk){ 
        data += chunk; 
    });
    req.on('end', function(){
       req.rawBody = data;
       next();
    });
```

But the data event never fires!

Does anyone know how can I access my raw payload, so I can parse it myself.
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think in this case you're going to have to implement your own body parser, which you can set as `sails.config.express.bodyParser` or create a `config/express.js` file like:

```
var express = require('express');
module.exports.express = {

   bodyParser: function(options) {

    // Get default body parser from Express
    var defaultBodyParser = express.bodyParser(options);

    // Get function for consumung raw body, yum.
    var getBody = require('raw-body');

    return function (req, res, next) {

        // If there's no content type, or it's text/plain, parse text
        if (!req.headers['content-type'] || 
            req.headers['content-type'].match('text/plain')) {

            // flag as parsed
            req._body = true;

            // parse
            getBody(req, {
              limit: 100000, // something reasonable here
              expected: req.headers['content-length']
            }, function (err, buf) {
              if (err) return next(err);

              // Make string from buffer
              buf = buf.toString('utf8').trim();

              // Set body
              req.body = buf.length ? {content: buf} : {}

              // Continue
              next();
            });
           }

         // Otherwise try the default parsers
         else return defaultBodyParser(req, res, next);         
    };


}
```

You'll have to `npm install express` and `npm install raw-body`.  Note that this example uses the default Express body parser as a fallback, *not* the default Sails body parser which isn't exposed anywhere (and is mostly the same as Express anyway, sans the JSON retry).

Answer (score 7):

with newest version of Sails, using express is deprecated.
I needed to use a specific parser to get raw data from Stripe API.
Here is my code, maybe it will help somebody :

```
bodyParser: function(req, res, next) {
  var skipper = require('skipper')();
  var rawParser = require("body-parser").raw({type: "*/*"});

  // Create and return the middleware function
  return function(req, res, next) {
    sails.log.debug(req.headers);
    if (req.headers && req.headers['stripe-signature']) {
      sails.log.info('request using raw parser middleware');
      return rawParser(req, res, next);
    }
    // Otherwise use Skipper to parse the body
    sails.log.info('request using skipper middleware');
    return skipper(req, res, next);
  };
},
```

Comment: Can you please share more of this example. I'm having the same situation. I'm not sure where to put `bodyParser`.

Comment: bodyParser goes into config/http.js

Answer (score 1):

maxime's answer is mostly correct. minor modification needed as follows:

```js
bodyParser: function(req, res, next) {
  var skipper = require('skipper')();
  var rawParser = require("body-parser").raw({type: "*/*"});

  // Create and return the middleware function
  sails.log.debug(req.headers);
  if (req.headers && req.headers['stripe-signature']) {
    sails.log.info('request using raw parser middleware');
    return rawParser(req, res, next);
  }
  // Otherwise use Skipper to parse the body
  sails.log.info('request using skipper middleware');
  return skipper(req, res, next);  
},
```