# SailsJS: add a middleware before the defined express middlewares for debugging

Tags: sails.js

**General Problem**

Sails JS is built upon express JS, for debugging reasons I would like to inject a middleware or a function in Sails JS before cookieParser/bodyParser, I expect that Sails JS wrapped the following:

app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser());
etc...

I would like to inject my own middleware function before these injections, how can I do that? for example in order to track the initial request.

**Specific problem:**

I integrated with Passport JS, sensitive users info are in request (see below), I am pretty sure this is due to request parsing middleware like cookieParser/bodyParser, but I would like to know how to confirm this myself.

(I would also be happy for a confirmation from you)

When I print the request, the user information is there, specifically, the password ("password: '$2a$10$rfRptIm7o1BKD1Qdr7yPUeWVisEHyZciCdD0ebivLAm8PPVRUicES',")

Here is the partial request:

```
    _passport: 
    { instance: 
      { _key: 'passport',
        _strategies: [Object],
        _serializers: [Object],
        _deserializers: [Object],
        _infoTransformers: [],
        _framework: [Object],
        _userProperty: 'user',
        Authenticator: [Function: Authenticator],
        Passport: [Function: Authenticator],
        Strategy: [Object],
        strategies: [Object] },
     session: { user: '532ea818e6221c90251e9342' } },
    user: 
    { username: 'nizar',
     password: '$2a$10$rfRptIm7o1BKD1Qdr7yPUeWVisEHyZciCdD0ebivLAm8PPVRUicES',
     createdAt: Sun Mar 23 2014 11:23:36 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time),
     updatedAt: Sun Mar 23 2014 11:23:36 GMT+0200 (Jerusalem Standard Time),
     id: '532ea818e6221c90251e9342' },
```

while in the model I toJSON and deleted the password:

```
toJSON: function() {
  var obj = this.toObject();
  delete obj.password;
  return obj;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.General Problem**

For Sails 0.9.x, the middlwares loaded by the sails server are defined in [sails/lib/express/index.js](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/blob/stable/lib/express/index.js). As you can see, the custom middlware defined in `config/express.js` is used after `cookieParser`, `session`, `bodyParser` and `methodOverride`. To inject a custom middleware before `cookieParser` and `bodyParser`, you can override the cookieParser or modify `sails/lib/express/index.js` directly.

For Sails 0.10.x, you can define a custom `loadMiddleware` function (default implementation is in `sails/lib/hooks/http/loadMiddleware.js`) in `config/express.js`. Scott Gress has explained this in detail.

**2.Specific Problem**

If you don't want the request object to include the password information, call `toJSON()` in   the callback function of `deserializeUser`:

```
passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findOneById(id).done(function(err, user) {
    done(err, user.toJSON());
  });
});
```

and in the callback function of the strategy definition:

```
passport.use('local',
    new LocalStrategy({
      usernameField: 'userename',
      passwordField: 'password'
    },
    function(username, password, done) {
      User.findOne({ name: username}).done(function(err, user) {
        if (err) return done(err);

        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Unknown user'+username});
        }; 

        if (!user.validatePassword(password)) {
          return done(null, false, {message: 'Invalid password!'});
        };

        return done(null, user.toJSON());
      });
    }
));
```

Answer (score 1):

For Sails v0.10, you can follow the procedure in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21946577/345484) to insert custom middleware before the body parser. In v0.9.x, you'd have to create your own bodyParser callback and add the middleware in there; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21317986/345484) for more info.

However in your case I'm not sure any of this is necessary. Passport is adding user data to the request *object* on the server as a convenience, but it's not actually being *transmitted in the request*. So, there's no sensitive data out in the open--it's just in memory. Your only concern is to keep it from being sent back to the client, which you're already doing with your `toJSON` method on the `User` model.