# How can I access the raw data from the Stripe API in Sails?

Tags: stripe-payments, sails.js

I'm trying to set up a Stripe webhook in Sails, checking the webhook signature as described [here](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures). The signature is being returned in the same format as the Stripe example, but every test webhook returns:

```
No signatures found matching the expected signature for payload. Are you passing the raw request body you received from Stripe? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node#webhook-signing
```

To try and get the raw request body I've attempted to bypass the bodyParser middleware for this route in sails.config.http, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838905/sails-js-remove-bodyparser-middleware-for-a-specific-route), but if I do that then this.req.body is:

```
undefined
```

As an aside, I can see there is some integration with Stripe in Sails, but I can't find a pre-built webhook. If i'm re-inventing the wheel, please let me know, there is very little documentation on integrating Stripe with Sails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68236261/6569847

Update the commented out bodyParser under config/http.js to:

```
bodyParser: function(req, res, next) {
  var skipper = require('skipper')();
  var rawParser = require("body-parser").raw({type: "*/*"});

  // Create and return the middleware function
  sails.log.debug(req.headers);
  if (req.headers && req.headers['stripe-signature']) {
    sails.log.info('request using raw parser middleware');
    return rawParser(req, res, next);
  }
  // Otherwise use Skipper to parse the body
  sails.log.info('request using skipper middleware');
  return skipper(req, res, next);  
},
```